# Cannot std::cout an implicitly converted std::string

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, overload-resolution

I used to display an string by `std::cout << str << std::endl`, and thought an object implicitly convertabel to `std::string` can be also displayed in this way.

However, I notice that I was wrong. I cannot `std::cout` an implicitly converted `std::string` until I overload `operator <<` for std::string.

The following code demonstrates the mentioned stuff.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class X
{
public:
    operator std::string() const {
        return std::string("world");
    }
};

#ifdef OVERLOAD_STREAM_OP
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::string& s) {
    return os << s;
}
#endif

int main() {
    std::string s = "hello";
    std::cout << s << std::endl; // viable
    printf("---\n");
    X x;
    std::cout << x << std::endl; // not viable

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that, in STL implementation, the overloaded `operator <<` function for std::string type, is a little bit different (But I really really don't understand those template stuffs):

```cpp
  template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Allocator>
    std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
    operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os,
           const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& __str)
    { return __os << __str._M_base(); }
```

My questions:

1. What is the difference between STL's overloaded `operator <<` and my own overloaded `operator<<` for `std::string` type?
2. Why I cannot display the implicitly converted std::string object `x` with `std::cout`(compile error)?

Comment: That `OVERLOAD_STREAM_OP` bit, how do you think that's legal? You're adding an overload but none of the types are yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. What is the difference between STL's overloaded `operator <<` and my own overloaded `operator<<` for std::string type?

Your `operator<<` is non-template, while STL's one is template.

> 2. Why I cannot display the implicitly converted `std::string` object x with `std::cout`(compile error)?

Implicit conversion (from `X` to `std::string`) won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions), which makes the invocation on the template `operator<<` failing. On the other hand, non-template `operator<<` doesn't have such issue.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.